# CoffeeScript: Inline call delegation which works with function bindings

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, delegation

I have following CS code snippet:

```
class Ctrl
    constructor: (@security) ->
        ...

    isAuthenticated: -> @security.isAuthenticated()
```

which is translated to following JS:

```
Ctrl = (function() {
    function Ctrl(security) {
        this.security = security;
        ...
    }

    Ctrl.prototype.isAuthenticated = function() {
        return this.security.isAuthenticated();
    };
})()
```

As you can see `isAuthenticated` is a simple delegation to `security` object's method and creating anonymous function is redundant.
I want to avoid creating this additional call level and instead perform kind of 'inline delegation' which would translate to JS similar to:

```
Ctrl = (function() {
    function Ctrl(security) {
        this.security = security;
        ...
    }

    Ctrl.prototype.isAuthenticated = this.security.isAuthenticated;
})()
```

Following doesn't work, since it tries to bind `@security` to wrong object:

```
class Ctrl
    constructor: (@security) ->
        ...

    isAuthenticated: @security.isAuthenticated
```

Any clues ?

Answer (score 2):

You can hook up delegation in various ways but you have to be aware of two things:

1. What `@` is when you're hooking up the delegation.
2. `@security.isAuthenticated` probably won't work if `isAuthenticated` is called with a `this` that isn't `@security`.

**(1)** tells you what you need to attach the delegate functions to (see below). **(2)** is the usual "a function reference isn't really a method" problem in JavaScript; for example:

```
o =
    m: -> console.log(@)
o.m()        # Puts `o` in the console
f = o.m; f() # Puts `window` (usually) in the console.
```

So you have to keep `isAuthenticated` bound to `@security` or it probably won't work.

One simple way to add delegation is to attach a bunch of bound functions to `@` inside the `constructor`:

```
delegate = (to, from, methods...) ->
    for m in methods
        to[m] = from[m].bind(from)

class Ctrl
    constructor: (@security) ->
        delegate(@, @security, 'isAuthenticated', 'somethingElse')
```

Then you can say:

```
c = new Ctrl(s)
c.isAuthenticated()
c.somethingElse(11)
```

and the expected things happen. **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/we8gT/

One problem with that approach is that each instance of `Ctrl` ends up with its own `isAuthenticated` and `somethingElse` functions: they're not attached to the prototype so they're not shared.

But we can always create our own functions and take advantage of the fact that we can call code inside `class C`:

```
delegate = (klass, property, methods...) ->
    for m in methods
        do (m) -> klass::[m] = (args...) -> @[property][m](args...)

class Ctrl
    delegate(@, 'security', 'isAuthenticated', 'somethingElse')
    constructor: (@security) ->
```

A few things of note:

1. `::` is used to access the prototype so the methods will be shared.
2. We use `(args...) ->` to pass any arguments through to the `@security` method.
3. `@` at the `class` level is the class itself.
4. We use `do` to ensure that `m` is what we expect it to be when the delegated function is called.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4c87J/

You can do delegation but you don't get it for free.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an instance's `.security` object on the prototype. You need to create the `isAuthenticated` method in the constructor where you have access to it:

```
class Ctrl
    constructor: (@security) ->
        @isAuthenticated = security.isAuthenticated
        …
```

([translate](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Ctrl%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3A%20%28%40security%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40isAuthenticated%20%3D%20security.isAuthenticated))

Comment: The problem is that it's not being attached to `prototype`, as @muIsTooShort mentioned :/

Comment: No, that's not the problem but the solution! As I tried to explain, it's impossible to attach an instance-specific `security` method to the prototype. Either use my solution, or the "redundant" anonymous function on the prototype. That is basically what @muIsTooShort's `delegate` functions do in a generic manner.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ctrl = (function() {
    function Ctrl(security) {
        this.security = security;
        ...
    }

    Ctrl.prototype.isAuthenticated = this.security.isAuthenticated;
})()
```

would not even work in Javascript.

security would be undefined,and you'd have context (this) issues with isAuthenticated method anyway. You cant save a few strokes on that one.

EDIT :

PROOF : http://jsfiddle.net/camus/Ecd7K/

shows an error on the console

Comment: I tried it (changed the resulting JS translation with browser dev tools) and it works. Perhaps because whole `Ctrl` assignment is passed as an argument of another function. I shown only a snippet of a real code in this thread.

Comment: Well if it would work, then the coffeescript version would work too, which is obviously not the case since you are asking the question. The piece of code you wrote doesnt work, period , this.security.isAuthenticated doesnt exist in the scope where you are using it : PROOF : http://jsfiddle.net/camus/Ecd7K/

Comment: This works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/gY3qfZUQ1FDpqyPWpC9E. 
Perhaps it's because of differences in JS support on Plunker/JSFiddle.  Please don't get me wrong: Starting little bit of "Nah, you're not right" was least of my intentions - I'm just a curious geek.

Comment: You are cheating , this refers to window in Plunker(ie no proper sandboxing),not the Ctrl closure. so this.security is global! 

If I protect the scope properly with a closure (no globals) :

http://plnkr.co/edit/3Iz3frjtoGFuIJieaEQt?p=preview

Doesnt work.